# Ember: Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for server-account in an object passed to 'push'

Tags: rest, ember.js

I am getting a weird error. I am enter a form and it properly outputs the data as an object and send its via REST. But I am still getting this error when I do it everytime. I have changed the primaryKey to "_id". I tried "username" but it gave me a completely different error and was no use.

```
Object {username: "adas", password: "dasdsa", pincode: "dasdasdsadsad", centcoin: "0"}
ember.debug.js:19160 Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for account in an object passed to 'push'
    at EmberError (ember.debug.js:19083)
    at assert (ember.debug.js:6778)
    at Object.assert (ember.debug.js:18895)
    at assert (ember-data.js:646)
    at Class._pushInternalModel (ember-data.js:9725)
    at Class.push (ember-data.js:9701)
    at ember-data.js:10079
    at Backburner.run (ember.debug.js:294)
    at Class._adapterRun (ember-data.js:9950)
    at ember-data.js:10074
defaultDispatch @ ember.debug.js:19160
dispatchError @ ember.debug.js:19143
onerrorDefault @ ember.debug.js:32916
trigger @ ember.debug.js:51624
(anonymous) @ ember.debug.js:52618
invoke @ ember.debug.js:990
flush @ ember.debug.js:1054
flush @ ember.debug.js:862
end @ ember.debug.js:176
run @ ember.debug.js:298
join @ ember.debug.js:318
run.join @ ember.debug.js:23770
hash.success @ ember-data.js:12808
fire @ jquery.js:3305
fireWith @ jquery.js:3435
done @ jquery.js:9242
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:9484
```

AccountAdapter.js

```
createRecord(store, type, snapshot) {
            var data = {};
            var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.modelName);
            var url = this.buildURL(type, null, snapshot, 'createRecord');

            //serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, null, snapshot, { includeId: false });
            data = this.serialize(snapshot, {includeId: false});
            console.log(data);
            return this.ajax(url, "POST", { data: data });
        },
        urlForCreateRecord( type ) {
            return this._buildURL( type);
        },
```

AccountSerializer.js

```
import AccountsSerializer from "store/ServerSerializer";


export default AccountsSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: "_id",

    modelNameFromPayloadKey() {
        return "serverAccount";
    },

});
```

AccountsModel.js

```
import { attr,
    Model } from "EmberData";


export default Model.extend({
    username : attr( "string" ),
    password: attr( "string" ),
    pincode  : attr( "string" ),
    centcoin  : attr( "string" ),

}).reopenClass({
    toString() { return "accounts"; }
});
```

AccountsNewRoute.js

```
save() {
            const store = get( this, "store" );

            var model = get(this, "controller.model");
            store.createRecord("serverAccount", {
                //id: get(model, "username"),
                username: get(model, "username"),
                password: get(model, "password"),
                pincode: get(model, "pincode"),
                centcoin: "0"
            }).save().then((saved) => {
                console.log("THIS IS SAVED ADD ACCOUNT", get(saved, "pincode"));
                this.send("addAccount", saved);
                return saved;
            });
            //let account = this.controller.get("model");
            //let account = get(this, "controller.model");
            console.log("THIS IS SAVED ADD ACCOUNT", get(model, "username"));
            console.log("THIS IS SAVED ADD ACCOUNT", get(model, "password"));
            console.log("THIS IS SAVED ADD ACCOUNT", get(model, "pincode"));


        },
```

ServerSerializer.js

```
import {
    RESTSerializer,
} from "EmberData";
export default RESTSerializer.extend({
    isNewSerializerAPI: true,

    primaryKey: "_id",

});
```

The server should respond with this:

```
{
  "username": "dadsdsadsa",
  "pincode": "fdsfdsfd",
  "password": "fdsfdsfdsfds",
  "createdAt": "2017-02-21T07:33:53.870Z",
  "setUpdatedAt": "2017-02-21T07:33:53.870Z",
  "_id": "twY0MFUeNf4UP7XO"
}
```

Comment: The response you show at the bottom is different from quoted in the error message at the top. Anyway, you should share the parent serializer class. Most likely, something wrong happening there.

Comment: Hey, I add the serverSerializer.js parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using `RESTSerializer` which requires the payload to be wrapped into another object, e. g.:

```
{
  "account": {
    "username": "dadsdsadsa",
    "pincode": "fdsfdsfd",
    "password": "fdsfdsfdsfds",
    "createdAt": "2017-02-21T07:33:53.870Z",
    "setUpdatedAt": "2017-02-21T07:33:53.870Z",
    "_id": "twY0MFUeNf4UP7XO"
  }
}
```

Try using `JSONSerializer` instead.